# Westpac payway sample code

Tags: php

I'm doing a checkout with Westpac Payway.

Does any one have a sample php code for its integration.

Please share it to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this be a start for you :

Fontis created an extension in August (2009) that allows you to use Westpac's PayWay and QuickGateway with Magneto.

As bonky as PayWay may be, this may suit your needs. http://www.fontis.com.au/magento/extension/westpac

Answer (score 2):

There are two modes of integration:

- **PayWay Net** is browser based and the credit card numbers never hit your server (good for PCI).
- Under **PayWay API** your server makes an API call to PayWay with the credit card and transaction details.

To get sample code for **PayWay Net**:-

- Sign-in to PayWay
- Click "Setup Net" in the menu
- Click "Downloads" in the menu
- Download "PayWay Net Examples"

To get sample code for **PayWay API**:-

- Sign-in to PayWay
- Click "Setup API" in the menu
- Click "Downloads" in the menu
- You can then download the API software for Java, .Net, classic ASP, PHP and SOAP.

If these options don't exist in the menu then your facility is not setup right or you have not been given access.  You can request a free test facility from the PayWay helpdesk.